# Protractor Typescript- Adding custom functions to ElementArrayFinder/ElementFinder

Tags: typescript, protractor

Can anyone help me in adding custom functions to ElementArrayFinder/ElementFinder classes?I want to do this is my framework rather than protractor library.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-element-extend. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I looked into it. I really want to save myself of inheriting the BaseFragment and keep it simple. Do you/anyone know of something more traditional way of doing it like it is done using prototype inheritance - adding property to an object? example- ElementArrayFinder.prototype.getSomeText

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
 by.addLocator('cssMatchingText', function (selector, text, optionalParentElement) {
            var parentElement = optionalParentElement || document,
                matches = parentElement.querySelectorAll(selector);

            return Array.prototype.filter.call(matches, function (match) {
                return match.textContent === text;
            });
        });
```

it will be similar in typescript as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it. Just create a .ts file in your project and let it compile as other .ts file does in your framework. Here is the code [here](https://gist.github.com/Galileo1/93fd80bb57568f340888d8639a29b330)